# Unable to use port forwarding with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to bind my local port to remote mongo port as remote server is not directly accessible from local. Im trying SSH port binding like this.

```
ssh -L 27017:localhost:27017 <remote server>
```

when i try to open mongo shell locally using `mongo mongodb://localhost:27017`. mongo is connected to remote server but when i do the same from node app using mongoose. i am getting connection error. Can someone suggest system level solution to this problem.

```
Something broke!!! - MongoError: failed to connect to server [server1:27017] on first connect [MongoError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND server1 server1:27017]
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/user1/src/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:336:35)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at emit (events.js:169:7)
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/user1/src/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:280:12)
    at g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at emit (events.js:172:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/user1/src/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:187:49)
    at Socket.g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at connectErrorNT (net.js:1016:8)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:511:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:425:17)
```

Comment: does your `mongod` is start on any terminal?

Comment: nope. No mongod instance is active while open mongo from shell or from my node app. It stop mongod service before trying all this